# 500 error with MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, ejs

I am currently working on a simple project with the MEAN stack. I am attempting to connect to Mongo DB. Everything appears to be working okay until I attempt to place data onto my `index.ejs` file. Here is my code:

Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//mongoose Schema 

var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type: String, required: true},
    lastname: {type: String, required: true},
    homeworld: String
});

//compiling into model 
module.exports = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);
```

Index.js in routes folder:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Person = require("../models/person");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Person.find({}, function(err, persons) {
    if(err){
      console.log("ERROR!");
    } else {
     res.render('index', { persons: persons });
   }
 })
});
```

app.js file (Please note that this is only the top half, the only portion that I changed a little):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./app_server/models/db');
var routes = require('./app_server/routes/index');
var users = require('./app_server/routes/users');
var Person = require("./app_server/models/person");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

//Connecting to mongo DB
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/learn2A");

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Here is my index.ejs page:

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>

<h4>Database Items Here:</h4>
<!-- Looping through each entry in the database -->
<% persons.forEach(function(person) { %>
  <p><%= person.firstname %></p>
  <p><%= person.lastname %></p>
<% }) %>
```

Everything is connected fine and working until I go to the index.ejs page. Then I do NOT get an error but on my console I am showing:

GET / 500 23.966 ms - 35

If I take away all of the following lines:

```
<% persons.foreach(function(person) { %>
  <p><%= person.firstname %></p>
  <p><%= person.lastname %></p>
<% }) %>
```

Then my index.ejs page loads fine.

My folder structure looks something like this:

```
app_server
    models
      person.js
    routes
      index.js 
    views 
      error.ejs
      index.ejs
 app.js
```

Finally, I know that the db is working on the mongo side-I have one entry in there and can see it. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: what is the error traceback? there must be one...

Comment: I am not getting an error except for GET / 500 5.070 ms - 35 in my console that is the annoying thing. I have that little information to work on!

Comment: i would try to slim the app down to the most simple case. put logs in there and see how far it goes and then you will find out what part of the code fails.

Comment: just guessing but you are parsing `person` into the render function but then you loop over `persons` in your template.

Comment: If I change <% persons.foreach(function(person){ %> to this: <% person.foreach(function(person){ %>  I still get the same error.GET / 500 23.431 ms - 35
GET / 500 4.887 ms - 35

Comment: the error is definitely in the template. to make it consistent i would start do rename the var in `index.js` from `person` to `persons`. then use `persons` in the template. maybe try render `persons.length` to start with and see what is coming out. then you could render `perons[0].firstname`.

Comment: I changed var Person = require("../models/person"); to var Persons = require("../models/person"); as well as in the template but still have the same error. I agree that the error is in the template specifically in the last part of it because when I remove it everything works fine

Comment: no thats not what i meant. a model should be singular so `Person` but when you do `Person.find` the result should be called `persons` plural because you get an array back. and parse `persons` into the render function.

Comment: also `foreEach` is camelcase not all lowercase.

Comment: Now we made some progress...I now get a 304 error message... GET / 304 5.620 ms - - My code looks like the following: <% persons.forEach(function(person){ %>
  <p><%= person.firstname %></p>
  <p><%= person.lastname %></p>
<% }) %> I also updated how my index.js file looks as well above

Comment: 304 is not an error message its a status code. http code `304` means `Not Modified`: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question. The solution was that I placed the connection to the mongo db in my file for the current model. It was in app.js. So this line:

```
//Connecting to mongo DB
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/learn2A");
```

was moved from app.js over to the models folder and the connection was made and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

change your code like so:

indes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Person = require("../models/person");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Person.find({}, function(err, persons){
    if(err){
      console.log("ERROR!");
    }else {
     res.render('index', { persons: persons });
   }
 })
});
```

index.ejs

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>

<h4>Database Items Here:</h4>
<!-- Looping through each entry in the database -->
<% persons.forEach(function(person){ %>
  <p><%= person.firstname %></p>
  <p><%= person.lastname %></p>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: did that and still get the 304 error message in my console but the page is appearing-expect without the db info. Console is showing:  GET / 304 3.043 ms - -

Comment: as stated above `304` means `Not Modified`. how does the html look like? it might just be a css or html issue that its not showing visually. does the persons array have any documents?

Comment: Yeah, the html looks like you have it above. The persons document does have a one object in it. The dbs is called learn2A but the collection is called person. Does it matter if it is not persons? But when I type in db.person.find() I am showing one object is there with an id, name, last name etc. Do you want me to put my code on Github?

Comment: i mean the rendered html not the template. are there any documents in the db? can you add `console.log(persons.length);` after the `Person.find` query. looks like you have no data there.

Comment: When I do console.log(persons.length) I do get 0 which may be my problem-like the db is not connecting

Comment: so thats it. first debug your db connection and check if the person collection has any entries to start with.

Comment: ha, that is easier typed than done-not sure where I went wrong with no error messages. I know that I have something in the db on that side. I can check it and see it there.

Comment: sure but first you are not showing any effort in trying to solve the problem yourself. second i cant debug your db for you anyway. i am voting to close this question now.